# UICollectionView steals focus

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a header, some cells and a footer supplementary views. The header contains a `UISearchBar`. If I type something into the search field, the keyboard automatically dismisses after the first letter. I think it is caused by my `-searchBar:textDidChange:`, which contains code for refreshing the collection view (via `-reloadData`, because this is the only method I know which works).

My theory is, that reloading the `UICollectionView` causes it to become *first responder*, but that somehow does not work.

I have this line in my output every time the keyboard dismisses:

```
setting the first responder view of the collection view but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)
```

I attempted to overwrite `UICollectionView`'s `-canBecomefirstResponder`, but unfortunately that didn't work.

Any ideas how can I prevent `UICollectionView` to become the first responder after the reload?

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck restoring the search bar as the first responder after updating the table view:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
```